# KeyError when parsing JSON results in Python

Tags: python, json, typeerror, keyerror

I am encountering a `KeyError` when parsing `JSON` results in Python.  I've searched other questions relating to KeyError, but none of the answers has helped so far.  When I make the web request

```
https://property.melissadata.net/v4/WEB/LookupProperty?id=MY_LICENSE_KEY&t=&cols=GrpPrimaryOwner&format=json&ff=5933 NE Garfield Avenue, Portland, OR, 97211
```

from a web browser, it returns the result

`{"Version":"5.0.1.1043","TransmissionResults":"","TotalRecords":1,"Records":[{"Results":"YS02,YS07,YC01","Parcel":{"FIPSCode":"41051","UnformattedAPN":"R243379","FormattedAPN":"R243379"},"Legal":{},"PropertyAddress":{},"ParsedPropertyAddress":{},"PrimaryOwner":{"Name1Full":"PORTLAND PIEDMONT GUESTHOUSE L","Name1First":"","Name1Middle":"","Name1Last":"PORTLAND PIEDMONT GUESTHOUSE L"`...

The result of the Python code

```
import requests
import pprint
# api-endpoint
URL = “https://property.melissadata.net/v4/WEB/LookupProperty?id=MY_LICENSE_KEY&t=&cols=GrpPrimaryOwner&format=json”  
# location given here
location = "5933 NE Garfield Avenue, Portland, OR  97211"
# defining a params dict for the parameters to be sent to the API
PARAMS = {'address':location}
# sending get request and saving the response as response object
r = requests.get(url = URL, params = PARAMS)
# extracting data in json format
data = r.json()
pprint.pprint(data)
name = data['Records'][0]['PrimaryOwner'][0]['Name1Full'][0]
print('name: ' + name)
```

is

```
{'Records': [{'Results': 'YE01'}],
 'TotalRecords': 1,
 'TransmissionResults': '',
 'Version': '5.0.1.1043'}
>>> name = data['Records'][0]['PrimaryOwner'][0]['Name1Full'][0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'PrimaryOwner'
>>> print('name: ' + name)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

I would like to extract the Name1Full value of "`PORTLAND PIEDMONT GUESTHOUSE L`" from the JSON results.  I appreciate any help you can provide.

**Solution:**
This works when `PARAMS = {'address':location}` is replaced with `PARAMS = {'ff':location}`

Answer (score 1):

Given the piece of `json` you provide I believe you should try with:

```
full_name = data['Records'][0]['PrimaryOwner']['Name1Full']
```

Let's see how this work:

`[Records][0]` access:

```
{"Results":"YS02,YS07,YC01","Parcel":{"FIPSCode":"41051","UnformattedAPN":"R243379","FormattedAPN":"R243379"},"Legal":{},"PropertyAddress":{},"ParsedPropertyAddress":{},"PrimaryOwner":{"Name1Full":"PORTLAND PIEDMONT GUESTHOUSE L","Name1First":"","Name1Middle":"","Name1Last":"PORTLAND PIEDMONT GUESTHOUSE L"...
```

We then need see that `Name1Full` is a value for the `PrimaryOwner` key, therefore [`Records'][0]['PrimaryOwner'] access:

```
{"Name1Full":"PORTLAND PIEDMONT GUESTHOUSE L","Name1First":"","Name1Middle":"","Name1Last":"PORTLAND PIEDMONT GUESTHOUSE L"...
```

Finally we add the key `Name1Full` to access the specific value [`Records'][0]['PrimaryOwner']['Name1First']:

Returning:

```
"PORTLAND PIEDMONT GUESTHOUSE L"
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSON you pretty print in the second part of your question doesn't have a `'PrimaryOwner'` field which is why you are getting a key error.

```json
{'Records': [{'Results': 'YE01'}],
 'TotalRecords': 1,
 'TransmissionResults': '',
 'Version': '5.0.1.1043'}
```

I think the question is: *Why is your program getting different JSON data than your web browser?* I can't help you further with that but perhaps someone else can.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help.  This works when ```PARAMS = {'address':location}``` is replaced with ```PARAMS = {'ff':location}```

Answer (score 1):

I simplified the problem.  You are not getting what you think you are getting back.  This snippet below reproduces the problem, I have removed the extraneous code.

```
data = {'Records': [{'Results': 'YE01'}],
 'TotalRecords': 1,
 'TransmissionResults': '',
 'Version': '5.0.1.1043'}
 
name = data['Records'][0]['PrimaryOwner'][0]['Name1Full'][0]
print('name: ' + name)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works when PARAMS = {'address':location} is replaced with PARAMS = {'ff':location}